# Azure DevOps release pipeline with git-flow

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, git-flow

I'm attempting to configure a release pipeline in Azure DevOps (on premises) to support a git-flow strategy.  What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Commits to 'release/*' trigger a build of the software and publish to a location for QA
2. Commits to 'master' take the **same** software build (artifact) from step 1 and publish to Production location

So when I do a git-flow 'start release' the software is made available for testing/QA and when I 'finish release' it's made available to users.

My build pipeline works fine, it's triggered by the release branch and concludes with a Publish Artifact task.  My release pipeline uses this artifact and has stages for QA and Production but the Production stage never triggers.  For QA I've got an artifact filter for 'release/*' and on Production for 'master'.

Is there a way to trigger my second release pipeline stage on a commit to 'master'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general flow this won't work unfortunately. When you commit to release branch your building from release branch. When you commit to master branch you will have to build again for an artifact to be oriented from a master commit.

You'll either need to be happy with:

- 1 x build from commit to release OR master and release to both environments
- 2 separate builds for release to separate environments

Comment: I thought this might be the case, thanks for clarifying.  What I'm trying to achieve seems the obvious way to do things with git-flow so I'm surprised that it's not possible with a CI/CD system.  Maybe it's just 'obvious' to me!  I definitely don't want 2 separate builds otherwise what's being tested is not what is released to production

Comment: @Colin Baker If this answer clarifies your issue, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Git-flow requires merge to develop and master, so you should only be deploying to QA and Prod from master, not from the release branch. As soon as you have your code base ready for release you merge to master, Build your artifact, then release to QA. Once approved you promote the same artifact to Prod.

Unfortunately you can't achieve what you're requesting in any kind of development strategy or form of deployment, CICD or manual.

Comment: @Bevan I disgree. Git-flow allows for bugfixes on the release branch and the only way this makes sense is if you deploy to QA from the release branch.  Issues found during QA are then fixed on the release branch and then merged to develop and master when deploying to Production.  If you deploy to QA from master what would be the point of a release branch at all?

Comment: @Bevan I also disagree. Git-flow has the concept of release branches and they are deployed to QA. Any Bugs found for the current release on QA should be fixed in this branch. The release branch will only be merged to master if the release is tested and approved. After the merge of the release branch, the master branch will be deployed to prod. If you would merge the release to master before testing is done on QA you would not be able to make bug fixes on the prod/master branch without pushing new features from the release.

Answer (score 2):

For your issue, if you want to automatically trigger a deployment to different stages based on commits to different branches in a Build Artifact source, this is not feasible.

Agree with Bevan , if you only want to use a build artifact as source for release pipeline, you can set `Pre-deployment approvals` for `QA` and `Production` stages. When you want the build artifact from the `release` branch to be deployed to the `QA` stage, you can approve the deployment on the `QA` stage. When you want the build artifact from the `master` branch to be deployed to the `Production` stage, you can approve the deployment on the `Production` stage.

[image]

You can also create two build pipelines, one for the master branch and one for the release branch. Then create separate release pipelines for the two different build artifacts. One is used to deploy to `QA` stage and the other is used to deploy to `Production` stage.